# Is it possible to obtain the IP address from a HTTP Request

Tags: python, http, tcp

**I am trying to identify users that access my website. I know of assigning a cookie to them & identifying them that way. But is it also possible to use their IP address to identify them?**

I know of IP subclassing (is that the correct term) so if many users on the same network access my site & have subclassing, they will all have the same IP address but thats ok, I dont want my IP identification to be exact, its just a backup if the user has no cookie.

If I have a HTTP request can I get the ip address of the requester/sender? For example to get the browser type I check the HTTP (header?) user-agent. With my little knowledge of Data Communications, if the HTTP request does contain an IP address, wont it have the IP address of the last hop(router/switch) or am I thinking of TCP?

**I am using Python & cgi; so is there a way to determine the HTTP requesters IP address either by looking at the HTTP request, or maybe TCP packets(I never worked with TCP in python, how could I look at data packets in python?).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Use `cgi`, and `os`. The client's IP address is located in the `environ` variable with a title of `REMOTE_ADDR`. For example, the following will print out the client's ip address:

```
import cgi
import os

print "Content-type: text/html"
print ""
print cgi.escape(os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"])
```

Comment: thanks for the reply :). Will this be their IP address or the address of the last router/switch hop?

Comment: It will be the origin of the request, if you proxy the request say nginx -> apache you will get 127.0.0.1 in apache for the REMOTE_ADDR, if you didn't forward the data with: `proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;` in nginx, or similar, but then you need to check X-Real-IP instead of REMOTE_ADDR.